# Cannot ssh connect gcp instance via web

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have three Google Compute Engine VMs, all can be ssh into via iTerm, but I find two of them, cannot ssh via Google Cloud Platform Console website(I mean the `SSH` button).

When I try gcloud command line `gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "vm_name"  --project "project_name"`, I find the error bellow. I have follow the direction to create a firewall allow-ingress-from-iap to open 22 to 35.235.240.0/20, still cannot ssh via web,

and another vm is OK.

[image]
[image]

Comment: 0

Do your VM's have Public IP's ? or only private IP's?

Can you check your user has the "IAP-Secured Tunnel User IAM" permission?

Also, can you share a screenshot of the firewall rule you created?

Comment: How do you connect from your local machine? Do you have any special config? I've noticed you're explicitly setting the `--tunnel-through-iap` when trying to connect from the cloud shell. Is this deliberate?

Comment: You are using **alpha** release level commands and the error message is telling you that you do not have permission to use them. Use the GA commands: **gcloud compute ssh ... **